# Pandas dataframe shift column by date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a panel dataset which is indexed by Date and ID and looks something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2005-12-31', '2006-03-31', '2006-09-30','2005-12-31', '2006-03-31', '2006-06-30', '2006-09-30'],
              'ID':[1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
              'Value':[14,25,34,23,67,14,46]})
```

I'm trying to shift the values of the same ID by Date and Date can be non-continuous quarters. groupby.shift doesn't give me the right thing or maybe I'm missing something. Here is what I did:

```
df['pre_value'] = df.groupby('ID')['Value'].shift(1)
```

This does shift values of the same ID, but it ignores the date... note that for `ID==1`, the `2006-06-30` is missing and therefore the `pre_value` for its `2006-09-30` should really be NaN. I'm also looking into multiindexing or declaring the dataset as panel, but that complicates my other calculations. Is there any easy way to do this with dataframe?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you want exactly. Do you want something like this: `2005-12-31`, `1,2`, `14,23` in the dataframe?

Comment: @JoeR Sorry about the confusion. In the original df, the Value for 2006-09-30 and ID ==1 is 34 and there is no value for ID==1 at 2006-06-30. So when I calculate the 'pre_value', which is the value in the previous quarter (2006-06-30), pre_value should equal to NaN, instead of shifting the 2006-03-31 value to 2006-09-30.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just make a copy of the dataframe, shift `Date` by 1 (seems you want shift by a quarter), and then merge back to the original dataframe. To shift date, you can convert string dates to pandas period so shifting will be easier.

```
In [34]: df['Date'] = pd.PeriodIndex(df['Date'], freq='Q')

In [35]: df2 = df.copy()

In [36]: df2['Date'] += 1

In [37]: df.merge(df2, on=['Date','ID'], suffixes=('', '_lag1'), how='left')
Out[37]:
    Date  ID  Value  Value_lag1
0 2005Q4   1     14         NaN
1 2006Q1   1     25          14
2 2006Q3   1     34         NaN
3 2005Q4   2     23         NaN
4 2006Q1   2     67          23
5 2006Q2   2     14          67
6 2006Q3   2     46          14
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! And it seems if I sorted my df by Date and ID, I don't even need to groupby ID anymore.